# Why do I get "expected u32, found &{integer}" when pushing into a vector using iterators from the permutator crate?

Tags: vector, types, rust, slice

I wanted to create a function that returns a data structure with all possible combinations for a certain group of numbers: e.g.: for `[1, 2, 3]` return `[[1], [2], [3], [1, 2], [2,1], ..., [1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 3], ...[3, 2, 1]]`.

I understand that `c` and `p` are some kind of vector of `&integer`, but I cannot find a way to save them into an array or vector. I was trying to save it as a vector of vectors since I do not think it is possible to save them as a vector of arrays, since the arrays have different sizes. It's also not possible as an array of vectors since I do not know the number of combinations at the start.

How can I store all `c` and `p` in a data structure so that it can be returned and used outside?

```
use permutator::{Combination, Permutation}; // 0.3.3

pub fn init() -> Vec<Vec<u32>> {
    let actions: Vec<Vec<u32>>;
    let mut data = &[1, 2, 3];
    let mut counter = 1;
    for i in 1..=data.len() {
        data.combination(i).for_each(|mut c| {
            println!("{:?}", c);
            actions.push(c);
            c.permutation().for_each(|p| {
                println!("k-perm@{} = {:?}", counter, p);
                counter += 1;
                actions.push(p);
            });
        });
    }
    actions
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:10:26
   |
10 |             actions.push(c);
   |                          ^ expected u32, found &{integer}
   |
   = note: expected type `std::vec::Vec<u32>`
              found type `std::vec::Vec<&{integer}>`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:14:30
   |
14 |                 actions.push(p);
   |                              ^ expected u32, found &{integer}
   |
   = note: expected type `std::vec::Vec<u32>`
              found type `std::vec::Vec<&{integer}>`
```

**edit:**
When trying `actions.push(c.iter().cloned().collect())` it returns the following error:

```
error[E0277]: a collection of type `std::vec::Vec<u32>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `&u32`
  --> src/rl.rs:59:44
   |
59 |             actions.push(c.iter().cloned().collect());
   |                                            ^^^^^^^ a collection of type `std::vec::Vec<u32>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=&u32>`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::iter::FromIterator<&u32>` is not implemented for `std::vec::Vec<u32>`
```

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what the methods `permutation` and `combination`, etc. are. Perhaps you can remove them? It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: It is  a library I forgot to include it.

Comment: Don't include it if you can make the problem minimal instead.

Comment: Please paste the exact and entire error that you're getting — that will help us to understand what the problem is so we can help best. Sometimes trying to interpret an error message is tricky and it's actually a different part of the error message that's important.

Comment: Looks like you just need to tell the compiler the exact type.

Comment: So the thing is, it stays C is a Vec of &integers. If I declare actions as Vec<Vec<&u32>> then I need to put 'static on the return, and then the elements are all &integers instead of u32, I want the elements of the vectors to be normal integers

Comment: Where do you believe that your inner `Vec` is created?

Comment: I thought when I called "data.combination..." It would return a new vec structure? I do not understand what "c" is and how can I save it. It is weird because it says it is a Vec<&integer>.

Comment: You have a vector of references to integers, which you need to convert to a vector of straight integers. Try with `actions.push (c.iter().cloned().collect())`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When trying `actions.push(c.iter().cloned().collect())` it returns the following error...

This happens because `c` is a `Vec<&u32>`, and `.iter()` iterates over references to items, so `c.iter()` is an iterator over `&&u32`s. `.cloned()` removes one of the `&`s but not the second one. You could fix this by adding another `.cloned()` (or `.copied()`), but I prefer to use `.map`:

```
actions.push(c.iter().map(|c| **c).collect());
```

If you don't need to keep around the references, you can instead shadow `c` with a `Vec<u32>` to use inside the loop:

```
let c: Vec<u32> = c.into_iter().cloned().collect();
```

`cloned` works here because `c.into_iter()`, unlike `c.iter()`, consumes the `Vec<u32>` to return an iterator over `u32`s.

I also don't see a good reason to use `for_each` here in place of a regular `for` loop. Here's how I would suggest writing `init`:

```
pub fn init() -> Vec<Vec<u32>> {
    let actions: Vec<Vec<u32>>;
    let data = &[1, 2, 3];
    let mut counter = 1;
    for i in 1..=data.len() {
        for c in data.combination(i) {
            let mut c = c.into_iter().cloned().collect();
            println!("{:?}", c);
            actions.push(c.clone());
            for p in c.permutation() {
                println!("k-perm@{} = {:?}", counter, p);
                counter += 1;
                actions.push(p);
            }
        }
    }
    actions
}
```

`actions.push(p)` works here without `.into_iter().cloned().collect()` because `permutator::HeapPermutationIterator` does the cloning internally.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough description. I just had to use actions.push(c.clone) instead because c is being borrowed in the "3rd for" after being moved in the "push".
What is the difference between the for and the for_each here? Since in rust you can always use for to iterate over any iterable, right? I used the for_each because it showed up in some code example for this library.

Comment: Ah, sorry -- I didn't test this because I was at work. Added the `clone()`. If the order of `actions` is not important, you could also move `actions.push(c)` to after the third `for` loop to avoid having to clone it.

Comment: There's no semantic difference between `for x in y {...}` and `y.for_each(|x| {...});` but because the first one is dedicated syntax and less visually noisy I prefer to use it. `for_each` can technically be more performant in certain situations ([this article is a place to start understanding why](https://medium.com/@veedrac/rust-is-slow-and-i-am-the-cure-32facc0fdcb)), but it comes with other tradeoffs, so I recommend you normally use `for` and only use `for_each` when `for` happens to be slow or ugly for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to solve this that is very ugly but since I'm new at the language it was the best I could come up with.

The main problem seems to be that I have a Vec of references to integers instead of a Vector of integers so I changed it with a temporary variable:

```
            let mut temp:Vec<u32> = vec![];
            for z in c.iter(){
                temp.push(**z);
            }
            actions.push(temp);
```

Comment: If anyone has a better way of doing this please feel free to answer. The original question is a bit over complicated and if mods think this is too confusing feel free to close/delete the post.